# Naming Objects in JS

Tags: javascript, oop, html, object

How do I create dynamic names for objects in JS? I am pulling elements from a form (ex: First Name). I would either like to assign a number as the object name or just use the first name.

Comment: this is a strange request, why would you want to do that?

Comment: maybe I'm taking the wrong approach, but so far i've been pulling the name value from a <form>. Essentially I want create users, and toss them into localStorage as an array, however each time I create a user, it's just the same object being overwritten?

Comment: add that to your question, I've added an updated answer to reflect your specific situation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about variable names, but you can do so with property names

```
var string = "propertyName";

var obj = {};

obj[string] = "some value";

document.write(obj.propertyName); // some value
```

**As to your specific use case**

It might be better to use an array to maintain a list of users...

```
var users = [];  

var newUser = { foo: "foo" , bar: "bar" };

users.push(newUser);

var anotherUser = { foo: "foo" , bar: "bar" };

users.push(anotherUser);
```

This gives you an array of users.